# Adding a variable value in endpoint URL

Tags: https, salesforce, visualforce, apex

I am trying pass contact id as a parameter to one of the webservices and get value to update in account object. But i am not able to set contact records ID field as a parameter in end point URL.

```
List<Contact> ContactUpdate = [SELECT id  FROM Contact where Rep__c like 'CRM%'];
     String ContactID;
     HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
     req.setTimeout(60000); 
     req.setHeader('Accept','*/*');
     req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json'); // Content Type
     req.setMethod('GET'); 
     for (Contact c : ContactUpdate)
     {    
     ContactID = c.id;
     req.setEndpoint('https://xxx/xxxx/xxxxx/xxx/xxx-lookup? ContactID= {! ContactID});

     Http http = new Http();
     HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
     System.debug(res.getBody());

        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());

        String GMMID;
        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && 
                (parser.getText() == 'GCGMM')) {
                // Get the value.
                parser.nextToken();
                // Compute the grand total price for all invoices.
                GMMID = parser.gettext();
            }
        }
        //ContactUpdate.IsFutureContext__c = true;
        C.Group_ID__c = GMMID;
        update c;
        }
```

Could someone please guide me in adding variable as parameter in endpoint URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the body and removing it from your endpoint.

```
String body = 'ContactID=' + contactID;
req.setbody(body);
```